# Update an argument of a basic navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-safe-args

**The context:**
I want to pass a userId to a fragment UserFragment after he has logged in.
I use a new project Android type "Navigation drawer activity".
I use LiveData, so when the user is logged in, the observer of my livedata updates the idUser from MainActivity. I would also like to update the fragment argument in my Navigation Component...

```
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
               R.id.nav_home, 
               R.id.userDetailItemNav, 
               R.id.dashboardItemNav), drawerLayout)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

**My problem**:
I juste want to pass the value of userId as argument for the destination (the UserDetails fragment) when navigating... But I don't want to create an onClickListner and pass the argument in the bundle. I only want to use the Navigation component solution and therefore just change the value of the argument of the fragment declared in my Navigation Component
I added to my project the "Safe Args".
I added on one of the destination fragments a "theUserId" argument:

*In mobile_navigation.xml:*

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/dashboardItemNav">
     <fragment (...)  />
     <fragment (...)  />
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userDetailItemNav"
        android:name="com.example.smart.ui.user.UserFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user" >
        <argument
            android:name="theUserId"
            app:argType="long"
            android:defaultValue="-1L"
            />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

*In UserFragment.kt:*

```
// loading specifics arguments
val argument = arguments?.getLong("theUserId",999L)
Timber.i("userId from MainActivity: $argument")
```

**What i tried:**

My LiveData observer in onCreate() in MainActivity.kt is:

```
viewModel.user.observe(this, Observer { user ->
    if (user != null) {
       userId = user.id
       // TODO: here, change the value of my navigation argument theUserId
    }
```

I tried to adding an addOnDestinationChangedListner in my LiveData Observer (but it multiplies the Listner). I tried also to put after the observer, directly in the OnCreate of my MainActivity (seems better) :

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener {_, destination, arguments ->
    if (destination.id == R.id.userDetailItemNav) {
        userId?.let {
            val argument = NavArgument.Builder()
                      .setDefaultValue(it)
                      .build()
        }
    }
}
```

...but the userId value is updated **only after the second click** on the navigation item of my UserDetail fragment. I don't understand why.

I think this code is better to put in my Livedata observer:

```
var userId = 75   // 75 is from my Livedata for example
var myArgs = UserFragmentArgs.Builder().setTheUserId(userId).build()
```

... but I don't know what to do with myArgs... how to use it, how to inject it into the Navigation Component in order to the next time I click on the drawer item "Detail User", my argument "theUserId" is well modified and retrieved in the fragment UserFragment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `But I don't want to create an onClickListner and pass the argument in the bundle.` it sounds like you'll need to create an onClickListener and pass the argument in bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clean, but here is a solution that works. Unfortunately, this solution does not fully respect the spirit of the Navigation Component...

*In MainActivity.kt, in the onCreate ( ) function :*

```
viewModel.user.observe(this, Observer { user ->
    if (user != null) {
      userId = user.id
    }
}

// (...)

navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()   // close drawer when item is tapped
    val bundle = bundleOf("theUserId" to userId)
    when (menuItem.itemId) {
        R.id.userDetailItemNav -> {
            navController.navigate(menuItem.itemId, bundle)
        }
        else -> {  // for other destination without parameter
          navController.navigate(menuItem.itemId)
        }
    }
    true
}
```

**If you ever have a better idea** (i.e. being able to change the value of theUserId parameter directly in the observer), **I would take your advice with great pleasure** !.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the example from [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) is easily adapted for your use case.

Comment: I read this documentation yet, and searched here on stackoverflow and also on Google for examples, but in vain.

I think that the documentation explains how to use SafeArgs on a classic event (such as a button click, it's easy), but it does not explain how to just change the value of an argument that is defined in the fragment of the navigation graph. The documentation does not explain how to preserve the working spirit of the Navigation Component with SafeArgs. ... or I don't understand it, that's why I'm asking for your help.